# How to solve Web Service method name is not valid.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asmx

I have got the below error

*System.InvalidOperationException: CheckPageAccess **Web Service method name is not valid.**
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)*

My web method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void CheckPageAccess(string userid, Pages PageNo, bool IsPresentApprover = false)
{
```

Ajax Request

```
this.CheckPageAccess = function (UserID) {                         
    var response = $http({
        url: "WebServicenName.asmx/CheckPageAccess",
        dataType: 'json',
        params: { 'userid': UserID, 'PageNo': PageNo, 'IsPresentApprover': IsPresentApprover},
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Pragma': 'no-cache' },
    });
    return response;
}
```

This is working fine in debug mode, but when I publish above web method will not show in hosted link.

Comment: Don't paste images of errors.

Comment: Sounds like a file wasn't uploaded, the .asmx or the .cs file in App_Code folder. Did you change the name above? If you didn't, looks like a typo. (2 n's in `WebServicenName`.)

Comment: Is `$http` valid? Try using `$.ajax({...`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `aspnet_regiis -i` from the command line

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```

If the problem persists, add the following code to the first row under `system.webServer > handlers`

```
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode" responseBufferLimit="4194304"/>
```